# Is there any way to get distinct value along with row count based on that value in same model in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have 13 thousands+ items on my item table including similar tags (Json form) in multiple items. I don't have any relationship or model with items and tags. How can I get distinct values of tags with item count(item which contains this tag) on each tag without much memory allocation?

[image: tags of an item]

I want to display them in a table like this -

```
SL----------Tag-----
1-----------responsive [3 items available of this tag]
2-----------mobile [124 items available of this tag]
```

Item table is like -
[image]

Comment: Show us the Schema for the Items table and any other related tables(s) please

Comment: working on this table and I have to count items of this table based on the value of the tag of the same table.

Comment: Does the column `tags` hold one tag or a delimited list of tags?

Comment: list of tags as a JSON object like the mentioned example.

Comment: I think now you should be seeing the design error that was made in this table. It you had a Tags table and a link table to _whatever this is related to_ Then these counts would be sinple to achieve by simply counting the link table rows. With this design the process it far more complex

Comment: yes. I completely agree with you, mate. :) Previously I don't have any plan to count or displaying tags like this way. It's a completely new feature and the data I have stored is fetched from a third-party API on an everyday basis. So it's not possible to collect data right now or alter the table. That's why I'm asking for a solution if there's any with this structure. :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to achieve this through MySQL query, I'm thinking of a few steps to achieve this:

1. Convert [Item+each tag] combination as rows from the `JSON` values in `tags` column. I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54862423/10910692) but to generate the `sequenceNumber`, I'm using `WITH RECURSIVE` for dynamic values. Also  I'm using `LENGTH()` and `REPLACE()` method to get how many tags appeared in all items then uses `MAX()` to get the largest number. Here I use `rnum` as the sequence number.
2. `CROSS JOIN` the generated `rnum` above with your table (in this example name `mytable`) to achieve the operation like in the linked answer that I've referred to.
3. Adding `COUNT(*)` and group it by each tag where it doesn't return `NULL`.

And the end query is something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(tagsVal,' [', COUNT(tagsVal),' Items available for this tag]') AS tag 
  FROM
    (WITH RECURSIVE tblrows AS(
       SELECT 0 AS rnum, MAX((LENGTH(t)-LENGTH(REPLACE(t,',',''))) +1) AS maxtags
         FROM
           (SELECT Item, JSON_UNQUOTE(tags) AS t FROM mytable) A UNION ALL
            SELECT rnum+1, maxtags FROM tblrows WHERE rnum+1 <= maxtags)
            SELECT rnum, item, JSON_UNQUOTE(tags),
                  JSON_EXTRACT(tags, CONCAT('$[', rnum, ']')) AS tagsVal
              FROM tblrows t CROSS JOIN mytable m
       ) sq1
   WHERE tagsVal IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY tagsVal;
```

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38e122b02540fd6f9e7edb84797c1fd9)