# How to convert array into rows in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

i have a data in below format and length of array is dynamic:

```
col1                                                col2
['a@google.com','b@google.com','c@yahoo.com']  ['x@google.com','y@google.com','z@yahoo.com']

i want the data in this format:

col1             col2
a@google.com    x@google.com
a@google.com    y@google.com
a@google.com    z@yahoo.com
b@google.com    x@google.com
...              ....
```

data type of col1 and col2 is JSON

Comment: How are `col1` and `col2` defined in the database?

Comment: they are defined as json datatype.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906435/convert-json-array-in-mysql-to-rows?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786080/mysql-and-json-transform-array-to-rows

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249675/mysql-5-7-convert-simple-json-array-to-rows